# ListView with images in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: listview, windows-phone-8.1

I am new to WP8.

I have an app.

It makes an Web API call.

I get a list of items.

I want to display this list of items to the user with an icon to the left of it.

I think i should be using the ListView control.

i have spent quite sometime trying to find a simple example of this but cannot.

So, either:

1. I am an idiot
2. Someone will send me a link as to how to do this
3. Someone will post a simple example
4. I need to buy a good WP8 book (but I will have to wait a few days before delivery)

I am hoping someone will answer 3. and i will follow up with 4.  And yes I am sure I am 1.

UPDATE:

This my markup:

```
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <ListBox  Name="lstPremises"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" FontFamily="{StaticResource PivotHeaderItemFontFamily}" 
                  Background="{StaticResource AppBarItemBackgroundThemeBrush}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Image Grid.Column="0" Margin="12" Height="50" Width="50" Source="Images/Number-5-icon.png" ></Image>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" FontSize="36" Text="{Binding Caption}" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontFamily="Global User Interface"></TextBlock>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
```

And this is my code-behind:

```
public class Item
{
    public string Caption;
}
public sealed partial class Management : Page
{
    public Management()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        List<Item> test = new List<Item>();
        Item item = new Informed.Item();
        item.Caption = "Test One";
        test.Add(item);
        Item item2 = new Informed.Item();
        item2.Caption = "Test Two";
        test.Add(item2);
        lstPremises.ItemsSource = test;
    }
}
```

and this is the screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can get a working example from here 
http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2014/07/01/gridview-and-listview-controls.aspx
or this link too these both worked for me
http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Building-Apps-for-Windows-Phone-8-1/04
2nd one is the video tutorial example hopfully you will get it

Comment: Hi, thanks for responding. Those are the 2 links I looked at before. The video was just frustrating. I wanted them to get to the point. The sample code i copied and pasted (from the other link) and it came up with errors.  Also, it seemed obfuscated.  I am sure there are lots of properties/styles you can add to the listview but I do not want to view them all at once. I just want a simple code example.  I add in C# items to my listview with an associated image. That is all I want a this stage :)

Comment: check this link with code
https://github.com/MvvmCross/NPlus1DaysOfMvvmCross/tree/master/N-16-CollectABull-Part5

Comment: Hi, just been working through it all.  I am looking at the listbox example... should  I be still using listbox as that video link implied I should not? Also, whilst I got icons showing i have not got data showing. I will update my question to show you this. Thanks

Comment: I have seen the light. Thank You.